# C2664 cannot convert argument from 'initializer list'

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, templates, pointers

I have the following code that I'm running on Visual Studio 2017. This code is a simple exercise to implement a linear search on an array.

The template is used because the function will be used to any type of array, char array, int array, etc.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
int linearSearch(T* arr, int size, T varToSearch) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == varToSearch) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << linearSearch({ 'a','b','c','d' }, 4, 'd') << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error of the title and after a long search I did not find the problem.

The microsoft page regarding the error, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd.aspx), does not have relevant information to understand what is happening.

For me the function should work this way: I have the **typename T**, that will basically be an int or a char. Let's say it is a char.

When I'm passing **{'a','b','c','d'}** it will decay into a **pointer** and, **as the type of T is char**, I would have following:

```
int linearSearch(char* arr, int size, char varToSearch)
```

What for me should work normally.

**EDIT**

After reading the commentaries and giving a thought about the answers, this is what is happening if you are stuck on this problem also. Let's say you have this syntax in a function:

```
 void exampleFunction(char *text){ \\whatever}
```

And when using the function you pass this:

```
 exampleFunction({'a', 'b', 'c'}){ \\whatever}
```

If you are expecting {'a', 'b', 'c'} to decay into a pointer so that you can iterate with text[], **it does not**. With this syntax you will get an **std::initializer_list**, and **not an array**.

You could do the following:

```
 char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
 exampleFunction(arr){ \\whatever};
```

This way **arr** will decay into a **pointer**.

Regarding the problem in my code, I preferred to use a std::vector.

```
template <typename T>
int linearSearch(std::vector<T> list, T varToSearch) {

for (typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++) {
    if (varToSearch == *it) return (it - list.begin());
}

return -1;
}
```

Comment: No, a brace-init list does not decay to a pointer. What makes you believe it would?

Comment: This is an [`initializer_list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/), and it doesn't decay to a pointer.

Comment: Why not? For me arr will hold the first position in memory of the array passed to the function.

Comment: It would be nice. It would be convenient. Unfortunately that's not the way it works. I don't know why, my best guess is no one could come up with a good way to make it work and be bullet proof in the wide variety of cases in which it would be used..

Comment: @ForceBru For me initializer lists are used to initialize the members of classes. How come this is an initializer list?

Comment: @CaioCésarSilvaGomes: We must distinguish between a std::initializer_list and an initializer list.

Comment: @CaioCésarSilvaGomes, because this syntax constructs data of this type? And they can be used to initialize anything you want, not just members of classes.

Comment: @AndyG Got it, didn't know there was one in the std, so basically what I'm passing to the function is not an array and it won't decay, is that it? This is so strange.

Comment: @ForceBru I did not know that this syntax would construct this data type, for me it would create a simple array. So how can I pass an array in this case? Is there a solution for it?

Comment: @CaioGomes: Exactly! :-)

Comment: @CaioGomes, that would create an array in C, but not in C++. I think you could pass `{1,2,3,4}.begin()` instead, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't create array this way. This thing { 'a','b','c','d' } called initializer list, but it doesn't supported operator overload. So this you have 2 solution:
First create array before you called function.
Or you can change function declaration to accepting std::vector by value,and send them initializer list this should works. 
And sorry for my engilsh.

Answer (score 0):

as others mentioned you can not do that. you can use the vectors but for some reason if you can't, you can try c arrays or perhaps a better alternative std::array instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N>
int linearSearch(std::array<T, N> & arr, T varToSearch)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(auto& element : arr)//iterating through each element
    {
        if (element == varToSearch)
            return i;
        ++i;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 4> arr1 = {'a','b','c','d'};
    std::cout << linearSearch(arr1,'d') << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```